# Change of variables in Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $F$ is a probability distribution function with corresponding measure $\mu_F$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose moreover that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, increasing function. Then I claim that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} u \circ f \mu_F = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u \mu_{F \circ f^{-1}}.$$

Indeed, if $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F$ then the random variable $X_f:= f(X)$ has distribution function $F \circ f^{-1}$. We can therefore write:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} u \circ f \mu_F = \mathbb{E}[u\circ f(X)] = \mathbb{E}[u (X_f)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u \mu_{F \circ f^{-1}}.$$

I want to know what the analogous result is for decreasing continuous $f$. Obviously, in that case, $-f$ is increasing and we can write

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} u \circ (-f) \mu_F = \int_{\mathbb{R}} u \mu_{F \circ -(f^{-1})}.$$

On the LHS, however, I want to get the minus sign outside the integral. So my question is: do we have $$\int_{\mathbb{A}} u(-x)\mu_F(dx) =  \int_{\mathbb{A}} u(x)\mu_F(dx)$$ when $A = \mathbb{R}$, and what is the analogous result for general measurable $A$, or, in particular, $A = (a,b)$ with $a<b$?

This is a simple result when we use the Lebesgue measure but I cannot work out how to prove it with measures arising from distribution functions.

Many thanks for your help.

Frank.