# Integral of cantor function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Let $\phi$ denote the cantor ternary function and $\mu = \mu_{\phi}$ the associated measure. Let $\lambda$ denote the lebesgue measure. Compute the following integrals.

- $\int_{[0,1]} \phi(t)d\mu (t)$
- $\int_{[0,1]} \phi(t)d \lambda(t)$
- $\int_{[0,1]} td\mu(t)$

I have no clue where to start, any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the first and the third one, you may use the formula $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}f(x)=\left[\frac{f(x)^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{1},$$ valid for any continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ of bounded variation. For the second one, you may use $\phi(1-x)=1-\phi(x)$.

Comment: For the second integral see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21120/integral-of-the-cantor-function